# How to differentiate between an empty file that has no extension and a directory in java?

Tags: java, directory, zip

Let's suppose I have a zip file containing two elements: elem1 (created by linux command `touch elem1`) and elem2 (created by linux command `mkdir elem2`)

Now, in java, I use the following code to extract the content of the zip

```java
// ...
// Suppose we have a valid inputStream on a zip file
// ...

ZipInputStream zipInputStream = new ZipInputStream(inputStream);
ZipEntry entry = zipInputStream.getNextEntry();

while (entry != null) {
    int entrySize = (int) entry.getSize();
    File file = Paths.get(extractPath).resolve(entry.getName()).toFile();
    if (/*Condition to detect a directory*/) {
        System.out.println("This is a directory");
        FileUtils.forceMkdir(file);
    } else if (/*Condition to detect an empty file*/) {
        System.out.println("This is an empty file");
    } else {
        System.out.println("This is something else");
    }

    entry = zipInputStream.getNextEntry();
}
```

I would like to specify the right conditions to detect whether *entry* is a directory, or an empty file without extension. Knowing that these entries are still in memory and do not exist on the filesystem, the command `file.isDirectory()` always returns false; so I cannot not use it to check for directory.

Any ideas please ?

Comment: [ZipEntry.isDirectory](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/zip/ZipEntry.html#isDirectory--) would be a pretty obvious method to use.

Comment: Nit: `while ((entry = zipInputStream.getNextEntry()) != null) {` would be a way to avoid duplicating the assignment.

Comment: But it seems like according to the file format ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ZIP_file_format), [Standard](https://pkware.cachefly.net/webdocs/casestudies/APPNOTE.TXT)) ZIP files always contain a flag if the given entry is a directory or not (see for example section 4.4.3.2 of the Standard)...

Comment: Through trial-and-error testing, I found out some things about Windows` native file compression utility that will make your head spin. Included info in my answer.

Comment: MMasmoudi, did I answer your question?

Comment: @Kayaman You are right. This could be a possible answer for me too. Thank you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I created both an empty folder and an empty file without extension and evaluated them with the code below:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String path = System.getProperty("user.home") + File.separator + "Desktop" + File.separator;
    File file = new File(path + "EmptyFile");
    File folder = new File (path + "EmptyFolder");
        
    System.out.println("Is 'folder' a folder? " + (Files.isDirectory(folder.toPath())? "Yes" : "No" ));
    System.out.println("Is 'file' a folder? " + (Files.isDirectory(file.toPath())? "Yes" : "No" ));
}
```

The (not surprising) result:

```
Is 'folder' a folder? Yes
Is 'file' a folder? No
```

The reason why this works is because the function `Files.isDirectory(...)` looks in the file attributes set by the Operating System to determine whether the item being examined is a "File folder" or simply a "file". My assumption is that Zip programs do not contain such metadata (not even Windows zip). Therefore, "*isDirectory*" test cannot be performed using the `Files.isDirectory(...)` function. My quick research discovered that, the way to do this (and I am kind of shocked) is by examining the file name and check to see if the name ends with the file separator. In fact, this is how `ZipEntry.isDirectory()` works.

Attempting to zip an empty folder is not allowed for Windows zip (maybe allowed with other software?). However, I was able to include empty directories with 7-zip. That wasn't the only difference. The `isDirectory()` test failed when the zip was created with Windows zip because the file was skipped altogether. So, in order for this to work, ***create the zip file with zip software other than the one that comes with Windows***. Then,

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    String path = System.getProperty("user.home") + File.separator + "Desktop" + File.separator;
    FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(path + "Desktop.zip");
    ZipInputStream zipInputStream = new ZipInputStream(inputStream);
    ZipEntry entry = zipInputStream.getNextEntry();

    while (entry != null) {
        File file = Paths.get(entry.getName()).toFile();
            
        if (entry.isDirectory()) {
            System.out.println(entry.getName() + " is a directory");
        } else if (file.getName().endsWith(".lnk")) {
            System.out.println(file.getName() + " is a shortcut");
        } else {
            System.out.println(entry.getName() + " is a file");
        }
            entry = zipInputStream.getNextEntry();
    }
    zipInputStream.close();
}
```

Outputs for me:

```
EmptyFile is a file
EmptyFolder/ is a directory
How We Test Wireless Routers _ PCMag_files/ is a directory
How We Test Wireless Routers _ PCMag_files/00hSyhn9j5PNrcOot1tMzz9.1578945749.fit_lim.size_100x100.png is a file
...
etc
```

One last note... obviously, if a `ZipEntry` is not a directory, it is a file. Therefore, no `else if` is needed. That is, unless you would like to make a distinction between file types. In the example above, I wanted to check if a particular file was a shortcut. Just keep in mind that this is not necessary. The logic should only test entries for `isDirectory` and if the test fails, it is simply a file.

Comment: Very good analysis :)